# 'make' failing every other time

Tags: makefile

What may be causing `make` fail every other time (and thus succeed every other time) in the below case?

Reduced `Makefile`:

```
helm/%: $(HELMFILE_DIR)/[0-9][0-9]_%.yaml
    @echo $@
$(HELMFILE_DIR)/[0-9][0-9]_%.yaml: services/helm/%/[0-9][0-9]_*.yaml | $(HELMFILE_DIR)
    cp $? $(HELMFILE_DIR)/
$(HELMFILE_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(HELMFILE_DIR)
```

Console output from 4 consecutive `make clean helm/external_dns` calls:

```
# make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
mkdir -p ./helm/helmfile.d
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml ./helm/helmfile.d/
helm/external_dns


# make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
make: *** No rule to make target 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml', needed by 'helm/external_dns'.  Stop.


# make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
mkdir -p ./helm/helmfile.d
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml ./helm/helmfile.d/
helm/external_dns


# make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
make: *** No rule to make target 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml', needed by 'helm/external_dns'.  Stop.
```

**Edit - more info:**

1. Missing parts of `Makefile`:

```
HELM_DIR := ./helm
HELMFILE_DIR := $(HELM_DIR)/helmfile.d

.PHONY: build clean
.PRECIOUS: $(HELMFILE_DIR)/%.yaml $(HELMFILE_DIR)/%.values.yaml.gotmpl 

clean:
    rm -rf $(HELM_DIR)
```

2. What is interesting, while `make clean helm/external_dns` fails every other time, `make clean; make helm/external_dns` succeeds every time.
3. In the above parts of `Makefile` I have added support for numbering helmfiles (added prefix `NN_`, where NN is a 2-digits number from 00 to 99, to order helmfiles alphabetically). The original part of the code, which works is:

```
helm/%: $(HELMFILE_DIR)/%.yaml
    @echo $@
$(HELMFILE_DIR)/%.yaml: services/helm/%/*.yaml | $(HELMFILE_DIR)
    cp $? $@
$(HELMFILE_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(HELMFILE_DIR)
```

4. State of the filesystem:

```
# make clean
rm -rf ./helm
# tree
.
├── Makefile
├── services
│         └── helm
│             └── external_dns
│                 └── 40_external_dns.yaml
# make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
mkdir -p ./helm/helmfile.d
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml ./helm/helmfile.d/
helm/external_dns
# tree
.
├── Makefile
├── helm
│         └── helmfile.d
│             └── 40_external_dns.yaml
├── services
│         └── helm
│             └── external_dns
│                 └── 40_external_dns.yaml
# make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
make: *** No rule to make target 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml', needed by 'helm/external_dns'.  Stop.
# tree
.
├── Makefile
├── services
│         └── helm
│             └── external_dns
│                 └── 40_external_dns.yaml
```

I hope this is enough information to reopen the question.

Comment: Because the `clean` target (which you are not showing) removes stuff which the build requires. Without more details, we can't tell you exactly how to fix that; probably the dependency `$(HELMFILE_DIR)/[0-9][0-9]_%.yaml` should not use a wildcard, which produces an empty result when the wildcard doesn't match any files.

Comment: The order in which targets are made which do not depend on each other is, AFAIK undefined. So sometimes your `clean` removes the files which the other target needs, sometimes it is cleaning up in the proper order. The problem with cleaning is that it is, strictly spoken, a contradiction to all other targets which produce something. E.g. compiling a project doesn't work either with a `clean` on the same `make` call, you need to `make clean && make all`

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed.  There's enough information here to know what's wrong... in fact @triplee pointed to it in their comment. The order of running `clean` is not undefined: targets are built in the order requested on the command line and that's defined by the POSIX spec.  The only time it gets tricky is when you use `-j` to request parallel builds, then make could be running both the `clean` target and other targets at the same time which _can_ cause issues.  But there's no `-j` here.

Comment: My nomination to close was based on the lack of both details and debugging information; with the `clean` recipe but without access to the file system we would still need to speculate about what source files there are and how they relate to the target(s).

Comment: @MadScientist I stand corrected, but only halfway - undefined when parallelized is good enough  for me :)

Comment: Actually, the root cause is the wildcard matching of `[0-9]`. When `helm` does not exist, the first dependency is `helm/external_dns: ./helm/[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml`, which matches the next rule. When a file already exists, the first dependency is resolved as `helm/external_dns: ./helm/40_external_dns.yaml`, which doesn't match the next rule. I would present reproducible example in an answer if the question was not closed. :-)

Comment: @tripleee Can you please reopen the question? I have edited it and added load of debugging information.

Comment: I don't have the power to do that (@Cody could) but I have submitted my vote to reopen.

Comment: @raspy Reopened now.

Comment: Even with `-j` the order is _defined_.  It's just not _deterministic_.  Make always tries to build things in the same order, parallel or not.  The problem is when you introduce parallelism make will skip targets that can't be built yet and move on to other targets and since there's no way to know exactly how long things will take, that can result in different orders in different builds.  Of course, there's _never_ a correct time for a `clean` rule to run in parallel with build targets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is the wildcard matching. The first time, when `./helm/40_external_dns.yaml` does not exist, the pattern does not match any existing file, so it is kept intact:

```
$ make clean helm/external_dns -dpr
...
Considering target file 'helm/external_dns'.
 File 'helm/external_dns' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'helm/external_dns'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'external_dns'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'external_dns'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'external_dns'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml'.
  Trying rule prerequisite 'helm/helmfile.d'.
 Found an implicit rule for 'helm/external_dns'.
...
helm/external_dns: helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml
#  Command line target.
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'external_dns'
#  File does not exist.
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
...
# automatic
# < := helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml
...
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 5):
        @echo $@
```

However, upon second call the file `./helm/40_external_dns.yaml` does exist, so it matches the wildcard and is getting resolved. So now `helm/external_dns` does not depend on `helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml`, but rather on `helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml`. See for yourself:

```
$ make clean helm/external_dns -dpr
...
Considering target file 'helm/external_dns'.
 File 'helm/external_dns' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'helm/external_dns'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'external_dns'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
 Found an implicit rule for 'helm/external_dns'.
  Considering target file 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
   File 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml.yaml'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml.yaml'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'helm/helmfile.d/[0-9][0-9]_helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml.yaml'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'services/helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml/[0-9][0-9]_*.yaml'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'services/helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml/[0-9][0-9]_*.yaml'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'services/helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml/[0-9][0-9]_*.yaml'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   No implicit rule found for 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
  Must remake target 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml', needed by 'helm/external_dns'.  Stop.
...
helm/external_dns: helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml
#  Command line target.
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'external_dns'
#  File does not exist.
#  File has not been updated.
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 5):
        @echo $@
...
# Not a target:
helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  File does not exist.
#  File has not been updated.
```

The main thing is that glob patterns are not regular `make` features and as you can see there are some caveats when they will be expanded. And `clean` btw is not the only thing that fails. On a subsequent call your file will also not be updated should the source file change, for the very same reason that dependency `40_external_dns.yaml` is not `[0-9][0-9]_external_dns.yaml`. See for example:

```
$ make helm/external_dns
mkdir -p ./helm/helmfile.d
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml ./helm/helmfile.d/
helm/external_dns

# Edit the original file
$ touch services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml

# Note that it is not copied
$ make helm/external_dns
helm/external_dns
```

This file structure adds to complexity by having part of the filename as source directory name, but nevertheless I would calculate target file name to know exactly what has to be copied instead of random glob expansion, e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
HELM_DIR := ./helm
HELMFILE_DIR := $(HELM_DIR)/helmfile.d

.SECONDEXPANSION:

.PHONY: helm/%
helm/%: $$(addprefix $(HELMFILE_DIR)/,$$(notdir $$(wildcard services/helm/$$*/[0-9][0-9]_$$*.yaml)))
        @echo $@

.PRECIOUS: $(HELMFILE_DIR)/%.yaml
$(HELMFILE_DIR)/%.yaml: $$(wildcard services/helm/$$(subst $$(firstword $$(subst _, ,$$*))_,,$$*)/$$*.yaml) | $(HELMFILE_DIR)
        cp $< $@

$(HELMFILE_DIR):
        mkdir -p $(HELMFILE_DIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(HELM_DIR)
```

Output:

```
$ make helm/external_dns
mkdir -p ./helm/helmfile.d
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml
helm/external_dns

# Nothing to do on next call
$ make helm/external_dns
helm/external_dns

# Update file if changed
$ touch services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml
$ make helm/external_dns
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml
helm/external_dns

# And the clean is fixed
$ make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
mkdir -p ./helm/helmfile.d
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml
helm/external_dns

$ make clean helm/external_dns
rm -rf ./helm
mkdir -p ./helm/helmfile.d
cp services/helm/external_dns/40_external_dns.yaml helm/helmfile.d/40_external_dns.yaml
helm/external_dns
```